# How do I add a \n at the end of each line

Tags: python, python-2.7, newline

Below is my code:

```
import requests

html = requests.get(

html_str = html.content
Html_file= open("fb_remodel.txt",'w')
Html_file.write(html_str)
Html_file.close()
```

This produces a text file which

```
{"data":[{"id":"359434924192565_361115077357883","created_time":"2013-11-05T18:52:24+0000"},{"id":"116929191671920_664658976898936","created_time":"2013-11-05T18:51:57+0000"},
```

I want there to be a newline right after every `},`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving a JSON value without any newlines; you'll have to manually insert newlines yourself:

```
response = requests.get(...)
json_str = response.content
json_str = json_str.replace('},', '},\n')
with open('fb_remodel.txt', 'w') as json_file:
    json.file.write(json_str)
```

I replaced 'html' with 'json' in your code and improved the file handling a little (in the above code the `with` statement auto-closes the file object for you).

The code uses string replacement to replace all `},` strings with `},\n`, effectively adding in extra newlines the original response did not have.

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson. This also replaces `},` if it appears inside a string. This is apparently not a problem with OP's data set, but could be a problem generally.

Comment: @Robᵩ: True enough; you could parse the JSON with `json` and write it out with more whitespace too, but that seemed overkill here.

Answer (score 3):

You can "pretty print" JSON with Python's "json" module

See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Pretty printing:

```
import json
print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True,
...                  indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the JSON module to pretty print:

```
import json
json_pp = json.dumps(html_str, sort_keys=True,
              indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

Html_file= open("fb_remodel.txt",'w')
Html_file.write(json_pp)
Html_file.close()
```

I would also use:

```
html_str = html.text
```

As you may know, requests will decode the response to Unicode using the correct character set.